# How to determine if server closed connection (RST packet received) in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm using Socket class for my TCP connection. But my current problem is to determine exactly disconnect reason.
In both cases (if there's connection timeout or server closed connection) I receive SocketException with "Broken pipe" message. So how I can exactly determine disconnect reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys, not RST packet but FIN flag!

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868356/how-to-detect-fin-tcp-flag-in-java-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069218/how-do-java-tcp-ip-sockets-report-transmission-success-or-failure-to-the-applica

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get a different `Exception` thrown.  If you are talking about a connection then you should get a `SocketException` from a host which sends a reset (I think that's the `RST` packet) and a `SocketTimeoutException` if your connection times out.

If you are talking about IO then again, if the server drops the connection you will get a `SocketException` while if the IO times out (maybe just the read) you will get a `SocketTimeoutException`.

Here's the test program I used.  Of course I'm bleeding sockets like crazy.

```
    try {
        new Socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress(someIpThatHangs, 8000), 1000);
        fail("Should have thrown");
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // we expected it to timeout
    }
    try {
        new Socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress(someIpThatResets, 1000));
        fail("Should have thrown");
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // we expected it to throw an exception immediately on reset
    }

    // start our server
    final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
    int serverPort = 8000;
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", serverPort);
    serverSocket.bind(address);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.err.println("Got a connection");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    // wait for the server to start
    Thread.sleep(100);
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
    clientSocket.connect(address);

    try {
        // read until the server closes the connection
        clientSocket.getInputStream().read();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // expected socket exception
    }

    clientSocket = new Socket();
    clientSocket.connect(address);
    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(100);

    try {
        // read until the socket timeout expires
        clientSocket.getInputStream().read();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // expected read timeout exception
    }

    serverSocket.close();
    thread.interrupt();
```

Comment: Well, there one little problem: SocketTimeoutException occurs even if we just didn't received anything with read operation. Another words, SocketTimeoutException is not guarantee that connection was lost - it just says that we got timeout of read or accept command and didn't received anything during this time (100 ms in Your case).